# Is there any React DND library with NO Center point of drag?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I've searched for many libraries which support DND functionality in react components but, unfortunately, couldn't find any with NO centred drag point. All these I've seen they have an issue with long cards content. What I looking for is when start dragging your item in a list I need the item changes its position based on the mouse pointer, not the item centre point.

Any suggestions?

Two things need to be covered.
1) Multiple Targets (List of tasks similar to ZendHub)
2) Drag Point based on mouse position, not the centre.

This one is nice, but it drags based on Item Center :/
https://rafaelquintanilha.com/sortable-targets-with-react-dnd/

Answer (score 1):

Dnd kit is providing four different built-in collision detection algorithms.

- Rect intersection (default)
- Closest center
- Closest corners
- Pointer within

You can choose between those or you can build your own custom collision detection algorithm. The pointer within collision detection should fit in your case. Here is a dedicated [example](https://master--5fc05e08a4a65d0021ae0bf2.chromatic.com/?path=/story/core-droppable-usedroppable--collision-detection-algorithms) page and [related docs](https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/context-provider/collision-detection-algorithms#custom-collision-detection-strategies) for collision detection.

A short example would look like:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { DndContext } from '@dnd-kit/core';

function App() {
  return (
    <DndContext
     collisionDetection="pointerWithin"
    >
      {/* Components that use `useDraggable`, `useDroppable` */}
    </DndContext>
  );
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35350407)

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense so I updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks great, nice job!